# How to exclude from the selection, for example: Monday and Friday in the MudDatePicker component?

Tags: c#, .net, blazor

I have problem with Mudblazor framework, because i can't find solution to my problem
How to exclude from the selection, for example: Monday and Friday in the MudDatePicker component?
I using Mudblazor framework.

Kind regards,
Lukasz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `IsDateDisabledFunc` attribute on your `MudDatePicker` component:

```
<MudDatePicker @bind-Date="SelectedDate"
               IsDateDisabledFunc="CheckIsDateDisabled" />

@code {
    private DateTime? SelectedDate { get; set; }
    private bool CheckIsDateDisabled(DateTime date) => date.DayOfWeek is DayOfWeek.Monday or DayOfWeek.Friday;
}
```